# jquery cookie plugin - can't get it working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I have a topbar with some important info for my users on my website (just like stackoverflow lets you know when you reached a new badge you see this yellow bar on top that can be closed).

I simply want to have have that bar visible when a visitor comes to my site. Once he closes the bar a cookie should be saved and the bar should never appear again.

Therefore, I am using the jquery cookie plugin. Any ideas why that doesn't work?

```
    var topInfo = $.cookie('topinfo');
            
    if (topInfo) {
        $('#topBar').hide();
    } else { 
        $('#topBar').show();
    }
    
    $('#topBar .topBarCloser').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideUp({
            duration: 300,
            easing: 'easeOutQuint',
            complete: function() { 
                $(this).remove();
                $.cookie('topinfo', true, { expires: 1000 });
            }
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've set the expiration date to 1000 days.

Comment: Is a cookie a must? It doesn't seem like a good way to remember things that are "never" :) Maybe use ajax to save a value to the DB in order to signal the message has been closed? Or remove a value, might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which cookie plugin you're using, but if it's this one: http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

Then it says:

```
@param String name The name of the cookie.
@param String value The value of the cookie.
```

So value has to be a string - you've set it to boolean. This would probably mean that topInfo will always be true (because false as a string will be "false", which is true!) Try setting the cookie to a string value:

```
$.cookie('topinfo', "on", { expires: 1000 });

// and then...
if (topInfo === "on") {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another reason why $.cookie could not be working **(jquery.cookie doesn't delete a cookie)** - maybe not in this case, but in general may someone look at this page and need this information - is because you **set it for a specific path** but you're trying to delete it without setting the path again.

Example:
if you set the cookie like this

```
$.cookie("CookieName", "yourValue", { path: '/' });
```

and you try to delete it this way:

```
$.cookie("CookieName",null);
```

that will not work, you must write:

```
$.cookie("CookieName", null, { path: '/'});
```

or wathever path you choose before.

Comment: I'm very happy my info was useful :-)